# Compatibility chromedriver and selenium with the last version of chrome?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the latest version of google chrome: 83.0.4103.61 and in my pom.xml I have this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I try to launch my test I have this error :

> ```
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created:
>     This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
> ```

If I try to change the version to 4.0.0-alpha-5 (or 4.0.0-alpha-4, 3....), I have this error :

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/AbstractDriverOptions
> ```

Comment: If you are on Chrome v83, you need ChromeDriver v83. You can download it from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Selenium v3.141.59 is fine.